# Symfony2 How to add img to error404 page

Tags: symfony, twig

I create a 404error.html.twig in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`
And It works but I have to add a img to error page. I create a 404.jpg and put in 2 places. First app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/images/404.jpg and second `app/Resources/public/images/404.jpg`
In error file I put this code

```
 <img src="../../../images/404.jpg" >
 <img src="../../../public/images/404.jpg" >
```

I cleared cache, run assetic:dump, but img still not show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put images in app/Resources/public as if it is a bundle.

You can put it in /web/images directory and show it with

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/404.jpg')}}"/>
```

[look the symfony book here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)